# How can I swap the content between divs so that the content from say div 1 is inserted into div 2, and vice versa

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three divs, one being the main div, and the other two sitting below it with different content. I need to be able to exchange the content in div one with the content from div two, and while it does that, it puts the content from div one into div two. The same thing needs to happen with div 1 and 3. The below function puts the HTML from div two into one, but I can't seem to figure out how to "swap" the two of them so that one is then inserted into div two.

Markup

```
<div id="main" class="content one">Foo</div>
<div id="second" class="content two">Bar</div>
<div id="third" class="content three">Bar two</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.content.two').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content.one').html($('.content.two').html());
    $('.content.two').html($('.content.one').html());
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just use a temp variable to hold the initial value, put two into one, then temp into two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.content.two').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tmp = $('.content.one').html();
    $('.content.one').html($('.content.two').html());
    $('.content.two').html(tmp);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I think I've been staring at this toooooo long. I appreciate your quick reply my friend!